# .Net Core 2.2 Health Checks UI gives blank page

Tags: asp.net-core

I follow all the articles I can find including this one [Microsoft Health Checks article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/monitor-app-health).
The health checks work properly and the /health url of the application returns json, healthy status as expected.
**However, the /healthchecks-ui returns blank page**. On the console developer tools I can see the error, "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {" in .healthchecks-bundle.js:1.

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<Model>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        // Health checks services
        services
            .AddHealthChecks()
            .AddMemoryHealthCheck("memory")
            .AddSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]);

        services.AddHealthChecksUI();    
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            //app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions
        {
            Predicate = _ => true,
            ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
        });
        app.UseHealthChecksUI();

         app.UseMvc(routes =>
         {
             routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "default",
                 template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

             routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "defaultApi",
                 template: "api/{controller=MyController}/{action=Get}/{value?}");
         });
    }
}
```

appsettings.json

```
{
    "HealthChecksUI": {
         "HealthChecks": [
         {
            "Name": "HealthChecksService",
            "Uri": "http://localhost:42008/health"
         }
     ],
     "Webhooks": [],
     "EvaluationTimeInSeconds": 10,
     "MinimumSecondsBetweenFailureNotifications": 60
  }
}
```

I also tried using HealthChecks-UI but it didn't affect.
I included of course the nuget packages Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks (2.2.0) , AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI (2.2.35).
Again, the /health returns json indicates healthy application but the UI returns blank page with js error. (Tried on both chrome and IE).
The environment is a closed one so if the ui tries to refer external resources from the internet it will fail but I don't see such a call.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 problems with what you're doing:

1. You need to set the `HealthChecks.UI.Configuration.Options` correctly in the `UseHealthChecksUI` method.  You need to override the default paths and the `UseRelativeApiPath` and `UseRelativeResourcesPath` settings.
2. The path you are going to to view the UI in the browser (according to your settings) should be **/health-ui**

Here is the code I used to get your example working:

**appsettings.json**:

```
{
    "HealthChecksUI": {
         "HealthChecks": [
         {
            "Name": "HealthChecksService",
            "Uri": "http://localhost:42008/health"
         }
     ],
     "Webhooks": [],
     "EvaluationTimeInSeconds": 10,
     "MinimumSecondsBetweenFailureNotifications": 60
  }
}
```

**Startup.cs**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services
        .AddHealthChecks()
        .AddMemoryHealthCheck("memory")
        .AddSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]);

    services.AddHealthChecksUI();
    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    ... 
    app.UseCustomHealthChecks();
    ...
}
```

**ApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs**:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseCustomHealthChecks(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    const string healthCheckApiPath = "/health";
    return builder
        .UseHealthChecks(healthCheckApiPath,
            new HealthCheckOptions()
            {
                Predicate = _ => true,
                ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
            })
        .UseHealthChecksUI(options =>
        {
            options.UIPath = $"{healthCheckApiPath}-ui";
            options.ApiPath = $"{healthCheckApiPath}-api";
            options.UseRelativeApiPath = false;
            options.UseRelativeResourcesPath = false;
        });
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me:
I am using netcore 2.2 with AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI Version=2.2.2.

Inside my Configure method:

```
app.UseHealthChecks("/healthz", new HealthCheckOptions
{
    Predicate = _ => true,
    ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
});

app.UseHealthChecksUI(setup =>
{
    setup.UIPath = "/healthchecks-ui"; // ui path
    setup.ApiPath = "/health-ui-api"; // this is the internal ui api
});
```

appsettings.json

```
"HealthChecks-UI": {
      "HealthChecks": [
        {
          "Name": "HealthChecksService",
            "Uri": "http://localhost:42008/healthz"
        }
      ],
      "Webhooks": [],
      "EvaluationTimeOnSeconds": 120,
      "MinimumSecondsBetweenFailureNotifications": 3660
  }
```